# Is it faster to create a new python array and initialize it to 0, or to create a copy of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, data-structures, time-complexity

I am confused about how much time it takes python to initialize a new array in Python.

Let's say I wanted to create an array of length n and eventually populate it with values.

If I already have an array of length n somewhere else in the program, would it be faster to just copy the array by doing: `newArray = oldArray` or would it be more efficient to create a new array by doing: `newArray = [0 for _ in range(len(oldArray))]`

I have also tried `newArray = [0] * len(oldArray)` but that seems to be the slowest option.

As a follow up, if some of the values in newArray needed to be the same as the old array (3 values? 100 values? more?) how does that change the answer? Would using a different data structure lower the creation time? How does appending to the array fit into all of this?

Comment: Please note that *newArray = oldArray* does **not** take a copy

Comment: Why don't you just measure which of the two is faster in your use case?

Comment: Do you realize that `newArray = oldArray` is *not* a shallow copy?

Comment: does it just set the reference of newArray?

Comment: @ChristopherOjo newArray will be assigned a reference to oldArray. Try: *newArray = oldArray.copy()*

Comment: @mkrieger1 The time varies whenever I run the program so I was wondering if there was theory for it

Comment: @ChristopherOjo Let's see your code and how you're timing it

Comment: I have been trying to time it using LeetCode or ```start=time.time()``` then create the array and subtracting the end ```time.time()```

Comment: Use numpy. You can initialize your array of zeros doing `np.zeros((N))` where N is the size of the desired array. If you just need to preallocate space without initializing values, you could use `np.empty((N))` but the gain in speed you will see is minimal.

Comment: so the fastest way to initialize an array is using numpy?

Comment: @ChristopherOjo Do you want to work with numpy arrays or Python lists?

Comment: I usually work with Python Lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **quick** benchmarking I've profiled proposed solutions with lineprofiler
(profileline is a decorator to wrap line profiling on a function)

```
import numpy as np
from scripts.profilestats import profileline

@profileline()
def main(n):
    old_array = list(range(n))
    l1 = old_array.copy()
    l2 = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    l3 = [0] * n
    n1 = np.zeros(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(100000000)
```

and we get this result :

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           @profileline()
     5                                           def main(n):
     6         1    1414275.0 1414275.0     13.2      old_array = list(range(n))
     7         1     374860.0 374860.0      3.5      l1 = old_array.copy()
     8         1    8747201.0 8747201.0     81.8      l2 = [0 for _ in range(n)]
     9         1     160812.0 160812.0      1.5      l3 = [0] * n
    10         1         30.0     30.0      0.0      n1 = np.zeros(n)
```

Unsurprisingly np.zeros is the quickest solution.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea numpy was that fast. I was also really surprised at how fast [0] * n solution and the copy solution were compared to the rest as I expected them to be way slower.